# Pulumi aws ec2 instance creation in default vpc and default subnet

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I am trying to create ec2 instance in default vpc and default subnet using pulumi typescript but not able to get any luck. Using below code to get default vpc id in script but not able to assign `Output<string>=string`.

`export const defaultvpc = new aws.ec2.DefaultVpc("default", {tags: {Name: "Default VPC",}}).id;`

I am getting vpc id in defaultvpc variable but not able to assign it as args in getSubnetIds

`const subnetIds = aws.ec2.getSubnetIds({vpcId: defaultvpc})`

if anyone knows how we will able to build ec2 instance in default vpc and default subnet then will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer and sharing it here

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import { VpcIpamResourceDiscovery } from "@pulumi/aws/ec2";

const config = new pulumi.Config();

// Retrieve the default VPC ID
const defaultVpcId = aws.ec2.getVpc({
    default: true
}).then(vpc => vpc.id);

// Retrieve the default subnet IDs for the default VPC
const defaultSubnetIds = pulumi.all([defaultVpcId]).apply(([vpcId]) =>
    aws.ec2.getSubnetIds({
        vpcId: vpcId
    })
);

// Create an EC2 instance in the first default subnet
const instance = new aws.ec2.Instance("my-instance", {
    instanceType: "t2.micro",
    ami: "ami-123456",  // Replace with your desired AMI ID
    subnetId: defaultSubnetIds.apply(subnets => subnets.ids[0]),  // Using the first default subnet ID
});

export const instanceId = instance.id;
```